# Need help with rotating different faces of a rubik's cube with python API. When different faces are rotated sequentially some cubes start to act up

Tags: python, animation, scripting

Pls help
now these first two rotations got animated fine

[image]

[image]

but in the third rotation one object started moving along a different axis
(even though there are other objects just like this one(been in the same roation before))
[image]

and when more rotations are added more blocks start behaving differently.

Here is a sample function:

The wrt_global is a list of dictionaries keeping track of the global axis to the axis of individual objects. (The commented out part is solutions I've already tried).

```
def rotate_front_anti(f):
obj=list(bpy.data.objects)
for sq in obj:
    sq.select_set(state=(sq.location[0]>=2))
    

#bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='MEDIAN')
ob=bpy.context.selected_objects

for i in range(0,len(ob)):
   ob[i].rotation_mode='XYZ'

for i in range(0,15):
    for j in range(0,len(ob)):
        ob[j].keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame = f, index= -1)
        ob[j].keyframe_insert("rotation_euler", frame = f)
    
        #ob[j].rotation_euler = (Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(-6), 3, 'X') * ob[j].rotation_euler.to_matrix()).to_euler()
        
        if wrt_global[int(ob[j].name)]['x'] == 'x':
            ob[j].rotation_euler.x += math.radians(-6)
        elif wrt_global[int(ob[j].name)]['x'] == 'y':
            ob[j].rotation_euler.y += math.radians(-6)
        else:
            ob[j].rotation_euler.z += math.radians(-6)
        #ob[j].rotation_axis_angle=(math.radians(-6),1,0,0)
        ob[j].location[2],ob[j].location[1] = new_coords(ob[j].location[2],ob[j].location[1],1,1,6)
        ob[j].keyframe_insert(data_path = "location", frame = f, index= -1)
        ob[j].keyframe_insert("rotation_euler", frame = f)
    f+=1


  
for  j in range(0,len(ob)):
    temp=wrt_global[int(ob[j].name)]['y']
    wrt_global[int(ob[j].name)]['y']=wrt_global[int(ob[j].name)]['z']
    wrt_global[int(ob[j].name)]['z']=temp




bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='MEDIAN')
return f
```

Answer (score 0):

Gimbal lock has been occurred for using rotation_euler. Can you try rotating matrix_local or matrix_world. It also has the advantage of simplifying the calculation of the rotation position from the rubik cube origin.